# Is it possible to 'overuse' session variables?

Tags: php, session, session-state

Is it possible to use session variables to the point that it significantly slows your application down?

I'm not trying to. I just want to know if session variables work well with large amounts of data.

Comment: Anything can be overused, it really depends on your definition of overuse or how large the data is

Comment: Might want to rethink your strategy if you have to use a lot of session variables. :)

Comment: Well, basically the definition is 'significantly slows the app down'. So, just to throw a number out there as a starting point, if I have 1 session variable that holds 1mb of data or I have 1000 session variables with a combined total of 1mb of data, would either of these cause a strain? Is one better than the other? Is it all moot? ;)

Comment: A single variable with 1mb of data can be handled easily by modern computers, but that's just a bad practice unless strictly necessary.

Comment: Fortunately I don't think I am anywhere near using them to such extremes. Thanks to you all who responded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you store session data. Default session store is file system based, each session has its own file. The file is loaded automatically on page load. The larger the file becomes, the longer it takes to load it. After it's loaded, it's just an associative array. Each item can be accessed in log(n) time (most probably).

However, if you have Redis (using [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis)) or some other session data store, you don't have to persist and load the data on each page execution, hence there is no performance penalty for storing too much data in session.

Comment: Right, of course. When I was reading about Session variables, I did read they were saved on the file system. It did not click in my head to think about it as a file rather then the memory object it appears as in PHP. Thanks.